# Разработка мобильной версии сайта

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Хочу сделать для сайта мобильную версию. Не просто адаптивный шаблон, а отдельно мобильную версию. 
У меня такой вопрос. Как лучше ее делать, в плане верстки и css? может быть установить максимальную ширину страницы и размеры блоков задавать в % чтоб под разные экраны шло? или же бутстрап самый лучший вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать на bootstrap, это будет быстрее, но некоторым верстальщикам например мне, не нравятся их точки остановки. Минимальная например 767px. Я media запросами делаю, чтобы под 320px, 480px и тд. Так будет лучше юзабилити

Comment: то есть вы имеете ввиду для каждого разрешения свои параметры для блоков указывать?

Comment: Да, свои точки остановки для всех популярных разрешений.

Comment: не подскажите эти самые точки разрешений?

Comment: Я обычно ориентируюсь на ширину экрана 320, 480, 600, 900, 1200. Анализировал этот вопрос и статистика показывает что это самые популярные размеры, перекрывающие почти все потребности.

Answer (score 2):

Обратите внимание на документацию Гугл **[*Адаптивный дизайн*](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/responsive-design)** и *[**Конфигурация поисковой оптимизации для мобильных устройств**](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/)*. Вероятно вы можете применять последнее детище Гугл **[AMP](https://github.com/ampproject)** ++ **[образцы](https://ampbyexample.com/)**. Также вы можете применять фрамеворк **[jQueryMobile](https://jquerymobile.com/)** ++ **[образцы](http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/)**. По моему мнению, всё-таки более прогрессивным является адаптивный дизайн. В этом случае не требуется создание субдомена и дублирование контента. Но и для мобильного дизайна имеется различные техники.

Comment: https://ampbyexample.com/ => ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: ampbyexample.com - Открывается отлично. Попробуйте с другого устройства зайти.